# Reusing Redux-react async request action creator / reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I have this simple async request action creator using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for requests and [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to dispatch actions. I want to re-use the same action creator for different requests - so each request would have its own state. I'll try to show some code and then explain more. Here is my action creator

```
function responseOK(response){
  return {
    type: RESPONSE_OK,
    payload: response,
  }
}

function loadingChangedStatus(isLoading) {
  return {
    type: IS_LOADING,
    isLoading:  isLoading,
  }
}

function handleError(errorID){
  return {
    type: HANDLE_ERROR,
    errorID: errorID,
  }
}



export function makeRequest( URL){

  return function(dispatch, getSate){

      dispatch( loadingChangedStatus(true) );

      axios.get( URL )
        .then(function(response){
          dispatch(loadingChangedStatus(false));
          dispatch(responseOK(response));

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          dispatch(loadingChangedStatus(false));
          dispatch(handleError('connection_error'));
        });
  }

}
```

And my reducer **reducerRequest**:

```
export default function(state = {isLoading:false, payload:false,errorID:false}, action){

  switch (action.type) {

    case IS_LOADING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoading: action.isLoading,
      });
      break;

    case RESPONSE_OK:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          isLoading: state.isLoading,
          payload: action.payload,
        });
        break;

    case HANDLE_ERROR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          isLoading: state.isLoading,
          payload: action.payload,
          errorID:action.errorID,
        });
        break;

    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

**HERE STARTS MY PROBLEM**

I combine reducers like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import Request from "./reducerRequest";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // I WANT EACH OF THESE TO BE SEPARATE INSTANCE BUT USE THE SAME ACTION CREATOR / REDUCER
  defaults: Request,
  updates: Request,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

In my component:

```
function mapStateToProps( {defaults, updates} ){
  return {defaults, updates} 
}

function mapDispatchToProps( dispatch ){
  return bindActionCreators({ makeRequest}, dispatch);
}
```

PROBLEM:  I want to re-use my action creator for different requests. How can I

1. call `makeRequest('www.defaults.com')` and it ends up in `defaults`
2. call `makeRequest('www.updates.com')` and it ends up in `updates`

Now the only way I can image to solve this would be to write for every request its own action creator and own reducer - just lots of copy paste - that doesn't feel right.

How can I reuse my action creator and reducer to create 2 separate instances of `defaults` and `updates` in my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix your reducer actions per action:

```
export default function(namespace) 
   return function(state = {isLoading:false, payload:false,errorID:false}, action){

  switch (action.type) {

    case namespace + IS_LOADING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoading: action.isLoading,
      });
      break;

    case namespace + RESPONSE_OK:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          isLoading: state.isLoading,
          payload: action.payload,
        });
        break;

    case namespace + HANDLE_ERROR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          isLoading: state.isLoading,
          payload: action.payload,
          errorID:action.errorID,
        });
        break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
}
```

and then add the namespace

```
function responseOK(namespace, response){
  return {
    type: namespace + RESPONSE_OK,
    payload: response,
  }
}


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // I WANT EACH OF THESE TO BE SEPARATE INSTANCE BUT USE THE SAME ACTION CREATOR / REDUCER
  defaults: Request("DEFAULTS_"),
  updates: Request("UPDATES_"),
});
```

and then use the namespace when you call the make requests

```
call makeRequest('DEFAULTS_', 'www.defaults.com') and it ends up in defaults
call makeRequest('UPDATES_', 'www.updates.com') and it ends up in updates
```

HTH

Comment: Cool, thanks it seems to be working.  I'm still new to Redux/React. Can you please enlighten me if possible. Is this considered towards best practice or its just some sort of hack or workaround to fill some gaps in Redux/React ?

Comment: It's pretty standard. The default `combineReducer` utility gives all child reducer functions a chance to respond to a given action, so if you use the same reducer twice in your reducer structure, they need some way to differentiate whether or not to respond. Also, there's a number of similar action/reducer wrapper utilities listed in my Redux addons catalog, at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links.  Think there's several that may do much of this work for you already.